# remove the word "out stock" in the label of product

Tags: inventory, products-management

How we remove the word "out stock" in the label of product in the catalog, although haven't in the inventory this product.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog > Manage Products` and search for the product you want to update.

In `General` Tab you'll find at the bottom of the list the `custom stock status` menu. Choose the right information.

I think with this you'll be able to select the good info for you.